# SystemC sensitivity list behaviour / driving the pins from main program

Tags: systemc

I am writing a simple System C program for simulating and logic. The sensitivity list has a ,b as its members . I want to drive 0 ,1 on these lines in the main program and as per the definition of sensitivity list my and-module should run and give me the new values.

```
#include<systemc.h>

SC_MODULE(digital_logic)
{
  sc_in<sc_logic> a,b;
  sc_out<sc_logic> c;

  SC_CTOR(digital_logic)
  {
    SC_METHOD (process);
    sensitive << a << b;
  }

  void process()
  {
    cout << "PRINT FROM MODULE\n";
    c = a.read() & b.read();
    cout << a.read() << b.read() << c << endl;
  }

};

int sc_main(int argc , char* argv[])
{
  sc_signal<sc_logic> a_in ,b_in , c_out , c_out2;
  a_in  = SC_LOGIC_1 , b_in = SC_LOGIC_1;

  digital_logic digital_and1("digital_and1");
  digital_and1 (a_in , b_in , c_out);

  sc_start(200,SC_NS);
  cout << "PRINT FROM SC_MAIN\n";

  a_in = SC_LOGIC_1;
  cout << c_out << endl;
  b_in = SC_LOGIC_0;
  cout << c_out << endl;
  b_in = SC_LOGIC_1;
  cout << c_out << endl;

  return 0;
}
```

I expected that since the signals on the sensitivity list changed the outputs will also change but this the o/p. How do I change the signals in the main program so that the and gate is simulated without writing a separate testbench.

```
OUTPUT
PRINT FROM MODULE
11X
PRINT FROM SC_MAIN
1
1
1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must put `sc_start()` between the point where you want to continue the simulation. Like following

```
a_in = SC_LOGIC_1;
b_in = SC_LOGIC_0;
sc_start(1,SC_NS);     // Add this
cout << c_out << endl;
b_in = SC_LOGIC_1;
sc_start(1,SC_NS);     // Add this
cout << c_out << endl;
```

In your original code, you just sequentially assign new value to `a_in` and `b_in`. It changes the current values of `a_in` and `b_in`, but it does not affect the current value of `c_out` because your program does not enter SystemC simulation kernel to simulate the change. So `c_out`'s next value won't be changed by your `a_in` or `b_in` sensitivity list.